# PHP Includes not working after moving pages into subfolders

Tags: php, include, subdirectory

The problem is as follows:

Originally, all of the individual pages on my website were in the root folder of the site.
I have now moved the majority of the pages into various sub-folders.

For example: The main page for our Apache Totem Freestanding Light Box used to be in the root folder, but is now in subfolders: /lightboxes/apache-totem-freestanding-lightbox/index.php

The problem is that various elements of the page have “PHP Modules” included for common elements such as the header, the breadcrumbs, the footer, the css file etc.

For example, for the header we have  as a link on each page.
The files that these “PHP includes” point to are situated in their own folder on the site root, called ‘modules’.

The trouble with this, is that the ‘PHP Includes’ can’t seem to find the modules because I guess they are expecting to see them in a folder called ‘modules’ that is situated in the same subfolder as the current page.
I’ve partially got around this by changing the link to the module to have ../../ in front to tell it that it has to look two folders up from the current folder, but the page is still having difficulties displaying all of the information.

To give you an idea of this, I have uploaded the Apache Totem Index Page in its subfolder /lightboxes/apache-totem-freestanding-lightbox/
https://www.w-co.co.uk/lightboxes/apache-totem-freestanding-lightbox/

As you can see, the main content of the page is displayed ok and the css file is doing its job with styling etc.
But there are various other problems, for example:
1.  There is an image missing from the header
2.  The quote button in the header and the content  is pointing to the wrong place (quote.php is on the root folder but the button is trying to link to the current subfolder)
3.  All of the items on the breadcrumb trail link to the current page
4.  All of the links in the footer are also trying to point to the subfolder lightboxes

Is there anything you can think of to fix these issues?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: What you have is a bunch of 404 errors, which all mean the same thing... You're using the wrong URL in your code.  You need to correct your URLs to point to the correct locations.

Comment: You can use .. to move up the root folder and the set the path.

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the images should be something like this https://www.w-co.co.uk/images/worldpay/visa.gif

You have to use base URL https://www.w-co.co.uk and then image path. You can define("BASE_URL", "https://www.w-co.co.uk") and use it like in the following.

```html
<?php 
define("BASE_URL", "https://www.w-co.co.uk/")
?>
<img src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>images/worldpay/visa.gif"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try  :)